# SVG animation by just adding a class

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, css-animations

I created an svg loader animation using SMIL animation. I am showing the svg inside an element by just adding a class name i.e `loader`.

[**Fiddle**](https://plnkr.co/edit/uvH9gJRhdpBnxyDcPH1L?p=preview) (*click on the container to view the loader*)

```
.loader{
    position: relative;
}

/* image */
.loader::before {
    background-image: url('loader.svg');
    /* other properties */
} 

/* blocker */
.loader::after {
    /* other properties */
}
```

But now, I realized the [SMIL is deprecated in chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL). So, I decided to handle animations using CSS. But if I handle animations using css, then I will not be able to manage the code as I am doing above i.e just by adding a class.

If I am using css animations, I need to add a new element inside the container and then use inline-svg concept, IMO.

Is there anyway, I can manage the animation by just adding a class when using css animations?

Some points:

- I don't want to add any new elements.
- I will use JavaScript just to add a class and for nothing else.
- I don't want to generate a gif (*a raster image*).

I have fiddles for both SMIL and CSS animations:

- [SVG using SMIL animation](http://codepen.io/Mr_Green/pen/MyEedK)
- [SVG using CSS animation](http://codepen.io/Mr_Green/pen/WwZxWV?editors=1100)

I am just limited only to add a class to manage the animation because it keeps my code organised and also I feel it is possible to do so with css animations as well.

Comment: I would not recommend using SMIL animations, as they're deprecated, and should be dropped soon. The only "true" way to animate SVG today is CSS animations (pending [Web Animations API](https://w3c.github.io/web-animations/)

Comment: @zessx I am saying the same in my post.

Comment: Whoops, missed it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can set the css animation in your loader.svg:

```
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <style>
    rect{
      animation:fill 1s linear infinite;
    }

    @keyframes fill{
      0%{
        fill:#f05223;
      }
      100%{
        fill:white;
      }
    }

    rect:nth-child(2){
      animation-delay:.25s;
    }

    rect:nth-child(3){
      animation-delay:.50s;
    }

    rect:nth-child(4){
      animation-delay:.75s;
    }
  </style>
    <rect width="50" height="50" stroke="white" fill="white"></rect>
    <rect x="50" width="50" height="50" stroke="white" fill="white"></rect>
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" stroke="white" fill="white"></rect>
    <rect width="50" x="0" y="50" height="50" stroke="white" fill="white"></rect>
</svg>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/tcbdwaSNgadrKYQr5iex?p=preview

Comment: I think this is the closest solution. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Made the svg smaller in size. [Fiddle](https://plnkr.co/edit/GzbNVSelzWMNdjuSEmCu?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

The deprecation notice was quickly [reversed](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/5o0yiO440LM%5B126-150%5D) in 2016 as much SMIL functionality still has no alternative. It’s not deprecated as of writing this even after 4 years.

Answer (score 0):

You can continue using SMIL, all you need is to add a polyfill to your page. It is easy (just add it to the page) and works perfectly on all browsers. I suggest you to start with Fakesmile ( https://leunen.me/fakesmile/index.html ). If you need something more advanced and with hardware acceleration, try the Google polyfill ( https://github.com/ericwilligers/svg-animation ).

Read this article for a broader explanation, a list of polyfills and a review of libraries you can use to animate SVG:
https://medium.com/@fmuaddib/the-following-are-the-possible-ways-to-create-professional-animations-in-svg-9d4caca5f4ec